# How to play audio from an API response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob, html5-audio, binary-data

I'm not able to play audio from the below response. How can I convert that below response and play it.

```
getAudio = async () => {
try {
const url = `example`;

const r = await fetch(url).then(r => r.text());
const len = r.length;

let audioURL = "";

if (len > 200) {
  const buf = new ArrayBuffer(len);
  const view = new Uint8Array(buf);

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) view[i] = r.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;

  const blob = new Blob([view], { type: "audio/wav" });

  audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
} else toast("No audio found!", { type: "error" });

this.setState({ audioURL });
} catch (e) {
console.log(e);
}
};
```

> Response is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're most of the way there. You already have an object URL, so try plugging that into an [`Audio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio) component and see what you hear!

Answer (score -2):

I would try to use Axios instead of Fetch, Its more useful in my opinion, Other than that, try setting up an error boundary around the definition of blob, I truly believes the problem lays there.

Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).